# How to handle C library ABI changes

Tags: go, bcc

There is an bcc library that eventually [changed number of arguments](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/commit/50f2009c7521e7d245372839cdb6b9cd6924202b#diff-5211ccc52ca5c1421d789cdca81f4cc10a789ed3a502df0a281e5e6a0e5011c3L248-R250) in `bpf_attach_uprobe()` function starting from version 0.17. There is also `iovisor/gobpf` library that [calls](https://github.com/iovisor/gobpf/blob/master/bcc/module.go#L284) `bpf_attach_uprobe()` using "C" package. The issue is that last version of Go library support only bcc library >= 0.17.

Is there any approach that allow to call `bpf_attach_uprobe` depending on C library version?

Comment: If there are breaking changes, version the Go package accordingly to support the different dependencies.